# How to load content of a text file and display it using ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview

[I'm quite new with Android programming so please excuse me for my nooby questions]

I'm developing a dictionary app. One of this app's feature is the Favourite button which allows user to save favourite words (short-click) and view the list of favourite words (long-click).

So far, I have succeeded in saving words into a text file (myfav.txt). The format of the content of the text file is as below (each item on a line):

```
    A
    B
    C
    ...
    Z
```

However, I have problem in loading and viewing this file inside my app. I'm thinking of using **ListView** to display the content of "myfav.txt" but I don't really know what to do. I have consulted the Qs & As from other similar posts here but found myself more confused as a result.

Therefore, my questions are:

1. How can I load content of "myfav.txt" and display it using ListView? **Could you please give detailed instructions as for beginners?**
2. Are there any better ways to do view the content of "myfav.txt" other than ListView?

Here is my code:

```
    //Reading lines from myfav.txt
    btnAddFavourite.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {         

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                setContentView(R.layout.text_view);

             //trying opening the myfav.txt
                try{
                       File f = new File(sdcard,"myfolder/myfav.txt");
                       InputStream fileIS = new FileInputStream(f);
                       BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileIS));
                       String readString = new String();
                       while((readString = buf.readLine())!= null){
                          Log.d("Content: ", readString);

                       //How to code to load/view the content of "myfav.txt" 

                       }
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e){
                       e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                return false; 

        }
    });
```

Thank you very much indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can find useful example [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidFileSystem/article.html).

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it's a good idea to use `ListView` for it. You'll need to provide [`ListAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) if you choose this way.

I'd recommend using `TextView` (if you don't need to edit your text) or [`EdiText`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) (if you do)

Comment: Many thanks. I am now able to save and load the file for views using TextView. But I'm also thinking of using SQLite method. I wonder if you have any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Using a file to save such information is not too sophisticated. I think you should look into tutorials about using SQLite, so you can store the words in a databse, and use cursors to view them in ListViews. You could use a separate boolean coloumn in you schema to mark favourited words that way for example.

Anyways, if you want to stick with files, one solution would be:

1. Read the contents of the file into a String array. You can use e.g. the Scanner class to easily read in lines from the file, and store them as separate strings in this array.
2. Construct a simple ArrayAdapter adapter class using this array.
3. Assign this adapter to a ListView.
4. Profit.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. I love doing it with SQLite db and have tried doing it. But it is not that simple because my SQLite db is not created by my app but converted using an external SQLite db manager. A gentleman here has recommended  me to add and extra table in the db for storage of the IDs of the favourite words but I do not know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

I am using following for writing to file -

```
    FileOutputStream fout = null;
    try {
        fout = openFileOutput(fileName, MODE_PRIVATE);          
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
        oos.writeObject(wordList);  //writing  arraylist<T>
        oos.flush();
    } catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

For reading -

```
fin = openFileInput(fileName);          
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
list =(ArrayList<T>)ois.readObject(); //reading in arraylist directly
```